# Text datatype doesn't perform well in where clause

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that is returning a few fields, most containing some customer information, and then 1 more that contains an xslfo "blob" in a text datatype field. I'm trying to optimize a process to ignore the records that don't have a value in this text datatype field, but when I add this to the where clause:

```
And cl.CorrespondenceFO IS NOT NULL
And Convert(varchar(1), cl.CorrespondenceFO) <> ''
```

The query times-out. I realize that the text datatype is being deprecated so I'll need to convert that column in the future, but I need to get this optimized before that occurs. Are there any suggestions on how I can get this stored procedure to return results with these two additional where clauses added in? TIA

Edit: I have updated the datatypes to varchar(max) and tried all of the suggestions below and the query is still timing-out. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I have a short query that you should consider: select 1 where Convert(varchar(1), ' a') = ''  will check true, so if you have a correspondence starting with space and followed by text, you will filter it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this to work. After taking the suggestions of converting my old text, ntext, and image datatypes to varchar(max), nvarchar(max), and varbinary(max) the query was still timing out. So here's the fix that worked.

Old version = 
Select FieldA, FieldB
From TableA
Where FieldA In ('value1', 'value2')
And Len(FieldB) > 0 -- this is what didn't work

New version =
     Create Table #temp
(
    FieldA varchar(10),
    FieldB varchar(max)
)

Insert Into #temp
(
    FieldA,
    FieldB
)
Select FieldA, FieldB
From TableA
Where FieldA In ('value1', 'value2')

Select *
From #temp
Where Len(FieldB) > 0

Drop Table #temp

(I'm not sure why my formatting isn't working, sorry)

For some reason, the query always timed-out when I tried to do the Len() check in the original query (may have something to do with the table being greater than 17 million records), so just generating a subset of records to deal with, then checking the Len() of that subset allowed me to get my records in a timely manner.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 4):

1. Convert to `varchar(max)` *now*
2. Fix your data on write by disallowing empty string with a CHECK constraint
3. Use `WHERE ... cl.CorrespondenceFO IS NOT NULL` *only*

I can't test, but the IS NOT NULL check should use the NULL bitmap

Alternatively, use a computed column with LEN (or DATALENGTH for text) and index/filter this.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE my_text_column IS NOT NULL` still shows lob reads for some reason so not sure on the `NULL_BITMAP`

Comment: @MartinSmith: probably because text I suspect. Thanks for testing

Comment: Tested on `varchar(max)` and similar results. Actually `text` gave me 1 lob read per `NOT NULL` value and `varchar(max)` two. Not sure if that's repeatable consistently or not yet though.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you still using `TEXT`? This should be `VARCHAR(MAX)`. Instead of the query you have, why not:

```
WHERE DATALENGTH(cl.CorrespondenceFO) > 0;
```

(Though I agree with @gbn - you shouldn't be allowing empty string if it means the same to you as `NULL`.)

Comment: I was being a bit too pre-emptive about using `VARCHAR(MAX)`

Comment: After I flagged this as the answer, I started googling about the restrictions for the varchar size vs text size and found out this will NOT work. The data in this text field is over 20000 characters long. If text is getting deprecated, which datatype should I be using since it looks like varchar(max) = 8000 characters?

Comment: VARCHAR(MAX) = up to 2GB. I'm not sure where you saw that VARCHAR(MAX) = 8000 characters, but that's wrong. If you define a VARCHAR that is *not* MAX, then the 8000 character limit is correct (you can't say VARCHAR(8001) or VARCHAR(20000)). This behavior is very easy to confirm on your own: create a VARCHAR(MAX) column and insert 20000 characters.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Aaron, I was just reading an article about how varchar would be saved in the row if it's 8000 or less and misinterpreted that to mean 8000 IS the max. I will go on my merry way, thanks again.

Comment: I've converted over all of the fields in my development environment and after trying to run the stored procedure again, I still get timeouts. I ran it through Database Tuning Advisor and it just suggests adding stats to tables/indexes. I tried adding an index to that field with the primary key and it won't allow it for the same reason that you can't index text datatypes. Any other suggestions on how to get my query to return results?

Answer (score 1):

Converting to `VARCHAR` doesn't sound very efficient, are you sure that `cl.CorrespondenceFO IS NOT NULL` isn't enough to filter rows with empty blobs?

If it really isn't enough, you could use `DATALENGTH` to avoid the conversion:

```
And cl.CorrespondenceFO IS NOT NULL
And DATALENGTH(cl.CorrespondenceFO) > 0
```

Comment: Yes, there are some records that have null, and some that are just empty. I'll try the DataLength thing and let you know.

Edit: even if I add just the "IS NOT NULL" then procedure times-out, can I just go with the DataLength check and call it good?

Comment: Update: doing    And DataLength(cl.CorrespondenceFO) > 0 still times-out.

Comment: indexed computed column or redesign is the only way then. Unless the addition of the `AND` just means you are getting a different (worse) plan and the `text` issue is a red herring.

Comment: "is not null" should be the fastest way as long as you stick to TEXT... glad to hear you can switch to VARCHAR(MAX) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with SQL Server, but if it's text type is anything like the MySQL/PostGres text type, it's going to be inefficient. Those types are stored off table, so the actual row only contains a pointer to the actual text blob. This means lots of disk seeks, an index won't do you much good, etc.